# VNC Viewer showing black cursor in visual studio with black color theme

Tags: windows-7, vnc, cursor, realvnc

(I asked on Web and Server fault exchanges and they told me to post this here)

I'm trying to read/write code remotely in VS2013 through VNC Viewer. I'm using a color theme in VS that has a black background. When I move my cursor over to the code (Where the cursor changes from a pointer to an I) it stays black. When I'm at home the cursor properly changes to white by default but through VNC it does not. Is there a way to fix this besides changing the color theme back and forth for when I work remotely?

Edit: I'm using VNC Viewer 5.2.1 64bit (RealVNC Ltd)

Comment: It's because the VNC client is drawing that mouse cursor, not the remote system.  Which VNC client are you using?

Comment: VNC Viewer from "RealVNC Ltd." (see the About box)?

Comment: I'm using VNC Viewer 5.2.1 64bit (RealVNC Ltd)

Comment: Hmmm you may want to look into using a sdiffernet viewer, I can't find an option in RealVNC's that allows the cursor (colour) to be changed...  But maybe someone has an actual answer, or can point to a specific viewer that has that option.

Comment: Thanks for being honest I appreciate it. Do you happen to know of any alternatives that wont have this problem?

Comment: Not really. TightVNC and UltraVNC come to mind.

Comment: Suggestion by @srk: Try setting UseLocalCursor to False (the setting is on the Viewer's Expert tab in the options dialog).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting UseLocalCursor to False (the setting is on the Viewer's Expert tab in the options dialog).

Comment: Welcome.  Answers are intended to be definitive.  Questions or diagnostics to help develop a definitive answer, or helpful suggestions that may or may not work should be posted as comments (which you don't yet have the rep to do).  I moved this information to a comment so that it won't be lost if your answer gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is indeed annoying, although 7 years later.

The solution in Windows 10:

Click the "Windows start" button, then "settings", then filter for the word "cursor" in the "Find a setting" input.

This way you can force a bigger cursor with your preferred color.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).